# Simplest way to search subfolders of main command folder?

Tags: discord.js

So this is my command handler code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for(const file of command_files){
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
        if(command.name){
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the simplest way to recursively search all the subfolders of `.commands/`, in such a way that I can use the commands within `.commands/fun`. I would prefer if the answer doesn't include the usage of a package to limit dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the level of depth that you want.

You can scan any directories mapped above a single time and later flatten your results, or create a recursive function (the former makes less sense as you'll have to map again).

**Note**: One thing I will point out is that it's dangerous to hard code file paths. These are not OS-agnostic — see [`path.sep`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep).

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function getFiles(directory) {
  const files = await Promise.all(
    fs.readdirSync(directory, { withFileTypes: true }).map(file => {
      const res = path.resolve(directory, file.name);

      return file.isDirectory() ? getFiles(res) : res;
    })
  );

  return Array.prototype.concat(...files);
}
```

Full implementation:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function getFiles(directory) {
  const files = await Promise.all(
    fs.readdirSync(directory, { withFileTypes: true }).map(file => {
      const res = path.resolve(directory, file.name);

      return file.isDirectory() ? getFiles(res) : res;
    })
  );

  return Array.prototype.concat(...files);
}

module.exports = async (client, Discord) => {
  const command_files = await getFiles(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'commands'));

  for (const file of command_files) {
    const command = require(file);

    if (command.name) {
      client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
};
```